# Cognito launch lambda when user added to a user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to trigger a lambda when a user is added in a user pool (any one) via an EventBridge rule ?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to log AWS Cognito in CloudTrail and then use EventBridge to trigger a lambda based on calls in AWS CloudTrail API from AWS Cognito.

1. It would be required to set a trail in AWS CloudTrail as mentioned in [Logging Amazon Cognito API calls with AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)
2. In EventBridge you can select an Event pattern from the service AWS Cognito User Pool and CloudTrail:

[image]

3. You may filter the lambda to be triggered from a single operation, such as [AdminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html)

List of support operations to filter the lambda trigger,[supported operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

You could also set a lambda as a trigger in AWS Cognito for a Pre sign-up or Pre-authentication on every user action instead of using Event Bridge.

As stated in the documentation [Customizing user pool workflows with Lambda triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html):

> You can create an AWS Lambda function and then trigger that function during user pool operations such as user sign-up, confirmation, and sign-in (authentication) with a Lambda trigger. You can add authentication challenges, migrate users, and customize verification messages.

To link a lambda as a trigger in AWS Cognito:

> 1. Create your lambda if does not exist.
> 2. In AWS Cognito, choose an existing user pool from the list, or create a user pool.
> 3. In your user pool, choose the Triggers tab from the navigation bar.
> 4. Choose a Lambda trigger, such as Pre sign-up or Pre-authentication, and then choose your Lambda function (Created before in AWS Lambda) from the Lambda function drop-down list.
> 5. Choose Save changes.